# How to implement one page site with silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

**Hello everyone**,
today i'm trying to create a one page site with SilverStripe.
i created a HomePage where i put all my pages so i have

```
HomePage
    Page1
    Page2
    Page3
```

In my HomePage layout, i loop to display my others pages content like this

```
<% loop Children %> 
    <div class="$URLSegment"> 
        $renderWith($ClassName) 
    </div> 
<% end_loop %>
```

I wanted some text items in my first page so i created them and created the appropriate function in my Page1.php like this

```
public function getTextItems(){
    return $this->TextItems();
}
```

...And i thought the text items would appear by calling the function in my layout.
It's actually my problem, nothing appears in my layout if i try to call some object from my children pages.
Does anybody know if there is a way i can make this running? Or maybe it's not the best way to do a one page...so if you have some hints, comon :)

Thanks!
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually for simple one-page sites I put everthing into the HomePage, without looping over its childrens. Anyway, I think your problem is that getTextItems() is defined into the Controller, while looping over Children() will extract just the Models.

Furthermore have a look to this quite new module, I just see it a few days ago (but never tested it):

http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/wernerkrauss/silverstripe-onepage

Comment: Yes, i figured it out for the my getTextItems function. What do you mean by "I put everthing into the HomePage, without looping over its childrens"?

Comment: For websites with lots of different content on one page I have used (versioned) dataobjects in the past. Since I have used this approach for quite a lot of websites now, I made it into a module: https://github.com/bummzack/page-blocks (the module is still under development, but feel free to check it out or contribute)

Comment: @bummzack I just seen your module a few minute ago, it seems promising. Added to my bookmarks :)